# Different subdomains, apache responding with the same vhost

Tags: domain-name-system, subdomain, apache-2.4, virtualhost, ubuntu-14.04

I have a VPS in Digital Ocean, running ubuntu 14.04 and apache 2.4.7, DNS is also managed in DO.

I have one domain let's call it thedomain.com I've been trying to configure 3 subdomains along with the main domain (thedomain.com, calis.thedomain.com, orlybg.thedomain.com, fubar.thedomain.com).

I haven't been able to correctly configure my apache's virtualhosts, in the browser no matter to what domain/subdomain, I go I always get responded by the same vhost (I can tell by the apache logs) and the otput in the browser.

The main domain and the 3 subdomains are A records www is a CNAME, here's my zonefile:

```
$ORIGIN thedomain.com.
$TTL 1800
thedomain.com. IN SOA ns1.digitalocean.com. hostmaster.thedomain.com. 1422028092 10800 3600 604800 1800
thedomain.com. 1800 IN NS ns1.digitalocean.com.
thedomain.com. 1800 IN NS ns2.digitalocean.com.
thedomain.com. 1800 IN NS ns3.digitalocean.com.
thedomain.com. 1800 IN A 104.236.80.93
www.thedomain.com. 1800 IN CNAME thedomain.com.
orlybg.thedomain.com. 1800 IN A XXX.XXX.XX.XX
fubar.thedomain.com. 1800 IN A XXX.XXX.XX.XX
calis.thedomain.com. 1800 IN A XXX.XXX.XX.XX
```

I have the main host and the 3 subdomains as 4 separated virtualhost files, I have these 3 enabled:

**calis.thedomain.com.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName calis.thedomain.com


    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/calis
    <Directory /var/www/html/calis>
        # enable the .htaccess rewrites
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted

    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error_calis.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access_calis.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

**thedomain.com.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName thedomain.com


    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/thedomain
    <Directory /var/www/html/thedomain>
        # enable the .htaccess rewrites
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted

    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

**orlybg.thedomain.com.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName orlybg.thedomain.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/myproject
    <Directory /var/www/html/myproject>
        # enable the .htaccess rewrites
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted

    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error_orlybg.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access_orlybg.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

I use a2ensite to enable the vhosts, I have vhost_alias.load enabled, I restart/reload apache in several ways, and no luck. I see tha the NameVirtualHost directive is not used in my version of apache, I used to have a conf file with ServerName localhost to not see the " Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name" error but I disabled it.

**apachectl -S**

```
VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
     default server calis.thedomain.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/calis.thedomain.com.conf:1)
     port 80 namevhost calis.thedomain.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/calis.thedomain.com.conf:1)
     port 80 namevhost thedomain.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/thedomain.com.conf:1)
     port 80 namevhost orlybg.thedomain.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/orlybg.thedomain.com.conf:1)
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/var/lock/apache2" mechanism=fcntl
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33
Group: name="www-data" id=33
```

I don't have a clue on what to try next, I've been trying for days. I'd really appreciate any help, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end a friend of mine saw that I have a typo in the vhosts and he added some entries in /etc/hosts with the domain and the server IP

```
thedomain.com        XXX.XXX.XX.XX
www.thedomain.com    XXX.XXX.XX.XX
orlybg.thedomain.com XXX.XXX.XX.XX
calis.thedomain.com  XXX.XXX.XX.XX
```

Answer (score 1):

I have two suggestions apart from this issue

1. Add `ServerName` with the FQDN of the host in which the Apache is serving the request. This will help you avoid lots of trouble.
2. If all of the sub-domains have different IP address then use IP based virtualization instead of Name based.

Your `VirtualHost` configuration looks perfect and it doesn't look creating the issue.

[Apache document states that](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/name-based.html).

> If no matching ServerName or ServerAlias is found in the set of
>   virtual hosts containing the most specific matching IP address and
>   port combination, then the first listed virtual host that matches that
>   will be used.

Generally different `VirtualHost` sections are selected based on the `Host:` HTTP header and if no `VirtualHost` section matches the `Host:` header then the first section will be considered the default and it will be served. And which inturn depends on how you make a request in the browser. You check it with `curl` command to be sure what is causing the issue like below.

```
$ curl -L http://localhost -H 'Host: thedomain.com'
```

This should return documents from `/var/www/html/thedomain`.

```
$ curl -L http://localhost -H 'Host: orlybg.thedomain.com'
```

This should return documents from `/var/www/html/myproject`.

Here with `-H` option we can send custom http header and so here we are using it to send `Host:` http header.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply! 1) The subdomains as I have them in ServerName is not a well formatted FQDN? 2) All domains/subdomains are in the same IP address in the server, so then I will continue with name base vhosts right? 3) I made the curl test, I got calis vhost content for all of the tests. I guess calis is the default then, but I don't know why all request get the default if there are other vhost to handle the requests 4) I don't see where the failure cause might be, I don;t find anything in the vhosts

Comment: 1) The FQDN which I was mentioning was related to your question about getting "Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name" error. 2) If they have same IP then name-based virtualization is the solution. 3) Yes calis is the default as the `apachectl -S` displays, but that will be default only for virtualhosts that are not configured. All your configurations are looking good i am not sure what is causing the issue. Better enable debug logs to identify the issue.

Comment: @orlybg once you have resolved the issue and found the cause please post it here in comments section so that I can know what caused this issue.

Comment: +1 for the curl localhost trick.  That helped me figure out the problem was with my browser (cached dns data) and not my server configuration.  Tried a different browser and it worked fine.